# What is the difference between `SDK_ROOT/ndk` with `SDK_ROOT/ndk-bundle`

Tags: android, android-ndk

[Android Studio Tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcmVB.png)

I have some ndk in SDK_ROOT/ndk dir, but Android studio can't recognize them.
I have to download a new one. Is there some difference between `SDK_ROOT/ndk` with `SDK_ROOT/ndk-bundle`

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I would assume that `ndk` refers to the [stand-alone NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) where as the `ndk-bundle` refers to the NDK that can be downloaded/installed via Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

"ndk-bundle" is the one that's included with Android Studio, whereas "ndk" is the standalone one

Answer (score 0):

`ndk-bundle` is referred to as the ndk shipped as part of Android Studio.
whereas in `ndk` you can have any number of ndk of different version.
Doing so helps you ensure reproducible builds across projects that each depend on a specific version of the NDK.